# Why forward with masking does not work for my site?

Tags: dns, shared-hosting, forwarding

My site address is http://rentapp-rentfromalex.rhcloud.com/.  I used 2 domain companies Aabaco and GoDaddy to forward to this domain and I used 2 different URL's.

Both have failures when using forwarding with masking.  Simple forwarding works fine.  Interesting that in the beginning of development forwarding with masking works fine to forward to this site http://rentapp-rentfromalex.rhcloud.com.  However, once the site became more complicated forwarding with masking stopped working, a user sees just an empty screen.

Comment: can you show me the goDaddy Domain Config file

Answer (score 1):

[X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) has been set to `DENY`.

It needs to be removed or set up with `ALLOW-FROM` properly.

Since you're using the Red Hat Cloud, OpenShift, you have control over that setting on your server.

If you give details about your server, I'll update the answer with ways to find and turn it off or change it.

This prevents anyone from masking the site in a frame to hide the URL.

To see the way to detect this in Firefox and watch the developer console while running the following snippet.

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; overflow: hidden }
iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; width: 100vw; height: 100vh }
```

```html
<iframe src="//rentapp-rentfromalex.rhcloud.com/" />
```

*Edit: I need detail about your server in the form of what image template, settings changed, etc.*

*Edit: Here's a screenshot of when you set up a new server and pick the image template*
[image: openshift image templates]

Comment: Tyler, I am using OpenShift

Comment: I need to know what image template you are using at the very least.

Comment: How to get image-template?

Comment: Added a screenshot of the image templates that are default. Are you using one of those?